# Play video using Kentico

Tags: kentico

We would want to play a video (size > 500 MB) in our Intranet, if I do it in our Intranet it takes too much time to load and play since the Intranet bandwidth may not be sufficient. It would be great if anyone help me to achieve this in better way.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are serving these video's exactly? What is not working for you? Why is the bandwidth insufficient?

Comment: I've uploaded video into Media Library (CMS Desk -> Tools -> Media) and then used WMP Video webpart to play a video.

Answer (score 1):

Prem, [akamai](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/media-delivery/adaptive-media-delivery.jsp) and [microsoft](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/smooth-streaming) offers smooth streaming technology, that adjusts to your bandwidth.

Comment: Also Vimeo allows you to limit your video to certain domains, so it wont be available anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

What Roman says or, for example, Picturepark Digital Asset Management solution. They offer a [Kentico DAM connector](https://picturepark.com/dam-connectors/kentico/).

Or, if you want a quick and easy solution, just put the video to YouTube and set it as "Unlisted" to exclude it from YT search and embed it in your intranet portal.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying anything else you should first consider compressing your videos with acceptable compression may be lossless compression and then think about any other solution.

This should be your first line of attack unless compressing a solution is not an option. I don't think this is a Kentico problem